# I want to search the username duplication in my database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select orders from table_name where usrname=username;",null);
```

usrname is the string which is entered in the edittext and username is which is already present in the database.

```
if(c!=null)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Username already exists,please use a different username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: please try to pay attention to mentors in chat

Answer (score 0):

change the condition

```
   if(c.getCount()>0) { 
Toast.makeText(this,"Username already exists,please use a different username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select orders from table_name where usrname=yourusername",null);
if(c.getcount>0)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Username already exists,please use a different username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```